# How to SET Default value in SQL Server case statement?

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario like to display Status and Count. Look at the below model

```
Status            Counts
---------------   --------
Completed          10
In Progress         6
Others              0
```

I have this code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN Status = 'I' THEN 'IN PROGRESS' 
       WHEN Status = 'O' THEN 'Others' 
       WHEN Status = 'C' THEN 'COMPLETED' 
    END AS ' Status', 
    COUNT(Status) AS ' Counts' 
FROM   
    table1
```

I have values for only `Completed` and `InProgress`. Currently I am getting only two rows. But I need three rows including `Others` and it's count should be 0 - how to do it in SQL?

Comment: What do you mean you are getting two rows do you have a `GROUP BY` you aren't showing us?

Comment: There must be a group by there since you have an aggregate. Can you share the whole query?

Comment: Yes i used GROUP  BY Status

Answer (score 16):

Add an "else", like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Status= 'I' THEN 'IN PROGRESS' 
         WHEN Status= 'C' THEN 'COMPLETED' 
         ELSE 'Others' 
       END            AS ' Status'
FROM   table1
```

Comment: The question is confusing that seems to indicate they want a *row* for the `Status= 'O'` group.

Comment: But In Progress and Completed Also chances to be null. in that case what i need to do the condition

Comment: very simple. i have a table and it contains many rows and some of columns , Status is one of the column , status have 3 states 1. Completed 2. In progress and 3. Others (column value like i,o,c). i need to get the counts for all three status . all the status may or may not contains values . if there no rows for that i need to show 0 as that particular status count

Comment: @kselva please provide a script to create and populate a table so we are able to test what you see, as well as the script you are currently using, since the one in your question is not 100% accurate

Comment: or consider like this

Comment: Status            Counts
---------------   --------
Completed          10
In Progress         0
Others              0

Comment: --create table table1(firstname varchar(100),lastname varchar(100),status char(1))

--insert into table1 values('Selvakumar','K','I')
--insert into table1 values('Arun','B','I')
--insert into table1 values('Rock','V','I')
--insert into table1 values('Wox','N','O')


SELECT CASE 
         WHEN status = 'I' THEN 'IN PROGRESS' 
         WHEN status = 'O' THEN 'OTHERS' 
         WHEN status = 'C' THEN 'COMPLETED' 
       END            AS ' Status', 
       Count(status) AS ' Counts' 
FROM   table1 

GROUP  BY status

Comment: i need output like 3 rows , the one i mentioned in top

Comment: copy the above sql and paste into sql

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you have a main table with status values in it, which I'll simplify to this:

```
CREATE TABLE #MainTable
(
    id INT,
    [status] NVARCHAR(1)
)
```

Your problem is that if there are no rows with the status `O` for `Others`, you're not getting a `0` when you group the rows to get counts.

I suggest you create a `Status` table to link to with a `RIGHT JOIN`. This will also get rid of the need for your `CASE` statements.

**Full solution:**

```
CREATE TABLE #MainTable
    (
      id INT ,
      [status] NVARCHAR(1)
    );

INSERT  INTO #MainTable
        ( id, [status] )
VALUES  ( 1, 'I' ),
        ( 2, 'I' ),
        ( 3, 'I' ),
        ( 4, 'I' ),
        ( 5, 'C' ),
        ( 6, 'C' );

CREATE TABLE #status
    (
      [status] NVARCHAR(1) ,
      [statusText] NVARCHAR(15)
    );

INSERT  INTO #status
        ( status, statusText )
VALUES  ( 'I', 'In Progress' ),
        ( 'C', 'Completed' ),
        ( 'O', 'Others' );

SELECT  s.statusText ,
        COUNT(t.[status]) StatusCount
FROM    #MainTable t
        RIGHT JOIN #status s ON s.status = t.status
GROUP BY s.statusText;

DROP TABLE #MainTable;
DROP TABLE #status;
```

**Produces:**

```
statusText  StatusCount
Completed   2
In Progress 4
Others      0
```

In the above example it joins on the `I,O,C` string values, which I would suggest that you replace with `ID` values. Then you could do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #MainTable
    (
      id INT ,
      statusId INT
    );

CREATE TABLE #status
    (
      statusId INT ,
      statusShort NVARCHAR(1) ,
      statusText NVARCHAR(15)
    );

SELECT t.id ,
       t.statusId ,
       s.statusId ,
       s.statusShort ,
       s.statusText 
FROM #MainTable t
RIGHT JOIN #status s ON s.statusId = t.statusId

DROP TABLE #MainTable;
DROP TABLE #status;
```